# Aggregation column category not found - when I set datashader = True with Hvplot

Tags: python, holoviews, datashader, holoviz, hvplot

I'm using Hvplot to create 2 scatterplots based on the category the data falls in.
Since there are so many datapoints, I'm using datashade.
My plot works fine when I don't use datashade.

**However when I set datashade=True in my code below I get the following error:**

> WARNING:param.dynamic_operation: Callable raised
>   "ValueError('Aggregation column category not found on :Scatter
>   [col1]   (col2) element. Ensure the aggregator references an existing
>   dimension.',)". Invoked as dynamic_operation(height=300, scale=1.0,
>   width=1200, x_range=None, y_range=None)
>
> ValueError: Aggregation column category not found on :Scatter   [col1]
>   (col2) element. Ensure the aggregator references an existing
>   dimension.

**Example code:**

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import hvplot
import hvplot.pandas

import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade

# create some sample data
sample_scatter1 = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, size=50)
sample_scatter2 = np.random.normal(loc=300., size=50)
sample_category = np.random.choice(2, size=50)

demo_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': sample_scatter1,
    'col2': sample_scatter2,
    'category': sample_category,
})

# this works fine if I would set datashade=False, but with datashade=True it gives an error
demo_df.hvplot(
    kind='scatter', 
    x='col1', y='col2', 
    by='category', 
    subplots=True, 
    width=1200, 
    datashade=True
).cols(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's trying to aggregate on the 'category' column, despite the fact that dimension has been grouped by. I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/pyviz/hvplot/issues/337) in hvPlot to hopefully address soon. For now you can use this workaround:

```
demo_df.hvplot(
    kind='scatter', 
    x='col1', y='col2', 
    groupby='category',
    width=1200, 
    datashade=True
).layout().cols(1)
```